# BaseActivity for Firebase user and Google user example

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

As i use in almost all activities firebaseauth user, and i need except the login activity the Google signed user in some activities, is there any axample of base activity for not copy paste all the code in all activities?

Or the real problem i got is how to have the google signed in user in another activity with no the need to make all the login cyrcle again?

For example for firebase user i have to copy paste in all activities the following code:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public  void  onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){
                checkCoins();
            }
        }


    };
```

More or less i used to copy paste the code. But now i need google signedin user, and of course some other things, so i thing Base activity is the best way for cleaner code. But i cant find any example for Google user.

Comment: *is there any axample of base activity for not copy paste all the code in all activities* - Yes there is. If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336). It uses Google sign-in authentication.

Comment: @AlexMamo      Actually my problem is to use both Firebase user and google user in a Base Activity, so not to have copy paste the same code all the time. Firebase was the easy part for me. I have hard time with google user in other activities or how to use the Google user in a Base activity. But thank you for the help.